# Excel VBA Add Method of SortedList Class from MSCORLIB.DLL Produces Compile Time Error: Expected: =

Tags: excel, vba, mscorlib

I'm writing some Excel VBA code and I'm using the `SortedList` class from the `MSCORLIB.DLL` as documented by Microsoft: [SortedList.Add (Object, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist.add?view=netframework-3.5).  I'm getting a compile time error that I just don't understand:

[image]

Here's how I included MSCORLIB.DLL into my project:

[image]

Additionally, I have the Windows feature `.NET Framework 3.5` turned on.

[image]

Why am I getting this compiler error?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis - It's not returning a value. `sl.Add "key", "Value"` - Or something like this - `x = sl.Add("key", "Value")` - You may get an Automation error then tho - At least it compiles.

Comment: Yes!  If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis for subroutines that do not return a value.

```
sl.Add "key", "Value"
```

Or if it does return a value, that's when you use parenthesis.

```
x = sl.Add("key", "Value")
```

You may run into an Automation error in this case tho.

But at least it compiles, and that's what your question was about (VBA syntax).

Comment: Also, adding `Call` eliminates the compile error.  E.g. `Call s1.Add("key", "value")`